# Changing a label in form1 from another class file

Tags: c#, winforms

I've written a C# program that runs entirely in Form1 and works great. The program is tiny, limited functionality but I want to create bigger programs and I want to make things more organized. As long as the other classes don't interact with the UI, everything works fine. But things go wrong when I try to modify something on the GUI from a different class.

After a day of searching and trying I'm stuck.

I've created a tiny testprogram with a single label and this works great:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace testapp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Changelabel1();           
        }
        public void Changelabel1()
        {
            label1.Text = "changedlabel1";
        }
    }
}
```

This changes label1 to display "changedlabel1". Great. Now I created a class 1 file, added label2 and modified my Form1:
Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Changelabel1();
    }
    public void Changelabel1()
    {
        label1.Text = "changedlabel1";
    }
    public string ChangeLabel2
    {
        get
        {
            return label2.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            label2.Text = value;
        }
    }
}
```

and created Class1.cs:

```
class Class1
{
    Form1 _mainForm;
    public Class1(Form1 form)
    {
        _mainForm = form;
    }
    public void ChangeLabelText()
    {
        _mainForm.ChangeLabel2 = "ChangedTheTextBox2";
    }
}
```

The first problem is that I can't seem to access Class1.ChangeLabelText() from Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Changelabel1();
        Class1.ChangeLabelText(); //This doesn't work

    }
```

It gives me an object reference error in return. I can get to Class1.ChangeLabelText() if I change public void ChangeLabelText() to public static void ChangeLabelText() in Class1, but then _mainform.ChangeLabel2 gives the object reference exception.

What am I doing wrong here?

Kind regards,

Comment: Where do you ever create an instance of `Class1`?  That is, where are you providing a value to its `_mainForm` member?

Comment: Where do you instantiate your Class1 ? You need an object reference that gets passed the form to do this. That being said, I don't think changing the UI should be subject to other classes, but rather the form itself. The business logic should be seperated into different classes, not the changes in UI

Comment: Yes, a better solution would be if the other class provided the text as string property. The form would retrieve this property and set the label itself. In a more advanced solution, the other class could expose an event, when the text changes. The form would then subscribe this event and get notified when the text changes.

Comment: I've read a lot of comments that say exactly the same. Separate logic and UI. However, I'd still like my logic to occasionally send something to the UI, like a statusmessage or something. Would it be possible for you to change my example to incorporate your solution? I've currently got about 100 tabs opened on this subject and I'm utterly confused :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Class1.ChangeLabelText(); //This doesn't work

You are calling the method as if it were `static` (meaning => `ClassName.MethodName()`). But it is not! this is why it does not work. You need an instance of the type `Class1`

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Class1 instanceOfClass1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Changelabel1();
        instanceOfClass1 = new Class1(this)  // create instance first
        instanceOfClass1.ChangeLabelText(); //  This should work
    }
```

> I can get to Class1.ChangeLabelText() if I change public void ChangeLabelText() to public static void ChangeLabelText() in Class1, but then _mainform.ChangeLabel2 gives the object reference exception.

You are not allowed to access class members in a static method. A static method is independent of an instance, but a class member is instance specific! meaning that each instance will have its own instance of the class variable. This is why making the method simply `static` will not work.